# Where to put auth in a turborepo?

Tags: next-auth, turborepo

I am trying to make a turborepo and am following the getting started instructions in these [docs](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/tools/prisma). I've used the [with-tailwind example](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/with-tailwind). I want to add prisma and mongodb and am getting stuck in how to establish the authentication flow.

I am trying to use this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mj_Qe2jBYS4) for guidance.

At this point, my file directory looks like this.

[image]

At 26.07 of the youtube video, the instructions are to add next-auth to the front end. It anticipates that I will be given a pages/api file that I can use to add it. I haven't got that file. I'm not sure if I can make it for myself, or if that interferes with the rest of the logic of the turborepo.

If I try adding the next auth packages to my apps/web package.json, I would need to add prisma there. If I add it to my packages/database folder, then I am missing react.

Should I make an entirely new package for auth? Can I make my own pages/api/auth...nextauth and where should I put the lib/prisma.ts file that is shown in the [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma) for making the adapter?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution?